Install Qt5 libraries on Debian 12
I would like to install the Qt5 libraries onto Debian 12, but I do NOT want Qt Creator.  I just want to be able to compile a C++ app which uses Qt5.  And I would like to use packages from default Debian repos (not Qt's own repo, or custom repos).
Most instruction assume I want Qt Creator, which I don't.  Experimenting is leading me to:
apt-get install qtbase5-dev

but it's not clear if that is complete.
